# Why does the new relief valve on my water heater leak?

Tags: water-heater

My pressure relief valve keeps leaking and I've changed it 3 times a temperature on the top is it 90 temperature at the bottom is it 90 I just converted to electric and so far it's been a pain in the ass any ideas on what I need to do to stop the leaking valve?

Comment: Can you please clarify? Your post doesn't make too much sense as-is. What do you mean by "a temperature on the top is it 90 temperature at the bottom is it 90"? Can you post link to pictures of the water heater?

Comment: Yes, punctuation and a proof-read, please. Where exactly is it leaking (at the threaded connection or through the valve itself)? Please add your response to the question.

Comment: What make and model is this heater?  Have you measured the pressure on the hot and cold sides?

Answer (score 1):

Check the pressure of the incoming water and add a pressure regulating valve if it is above about 100 psig. Where I live north of Pittsburgh, Pa. our water companies usually provide line pressure of 60 to 100 psig incoming water supply. Check with the water utility to see what pressure they supply and is it a steady pressure or a variable pressure. Also add a "potable water" expansion tank in the cold water line to the water heater. An expansion tank may be code in your area; it is in mine. Water expands when heated and can cause the relief valve to lift (drip/leak) when the cooler water in the tank is reheated after you have used some hot water. You used to be able to buy temperature/pressure relief valves rated at either 125 or 150 psi. I always preferred the relief valve set at 150 psig. as long as it does not exceed the pressure rating of the water heater tank.